# Patch multiple records in SSMS table from Power App

Tags: powerapps

I have an application that I want to have a mass update function. I can update individual records just fine, however updating a group based on a collection is eluding me. I have read every article from MS regarding Patch and ForAll functions and have not had any luck. For simplicity lets say my root table in SSMS is...

| UnitID | Status | Reviewer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | null | null |
| 2345 | null | null |

In my power app I have fields that are both prepopulated and user selected
Status - DropBox Selection
Reviewer - User().FullName

I have created a collection to capture the UnitID'd that I want to apply the changes to in the SSMS table through;

```
ClearCollect(
colMassEdt,
    Filter(
        'SSMS.Table',
        Entitlement = Drp_Entitlement_1.Selected.Value
    )
);
    
ClearCollect(
    colMassEdt_2,
    ShowColumns(
        colMassEdt,"UnitID"
    )
);
```

The colMassEdit_2 has a table with the UnitID's 1234 and 2345. I am trying to build a patch statement that will apply the Status variable and Reviewer Variable to each record in the source SSMS.Table that has a corresponding UnitID that is present in the colMassEdit_2. My latest attempt has been:

```
Patch('SSMS.Table',
    LookUp('SSMS.Table',UserAccessReviewID = colMassEdt_2),
    {
        Status:StatusMassUpd.Selected.Value
    }
)
```

It is not working and I have exhausted my knowledge bas3e and YouTube videos. please help if possible.